# Octave - Match Arrays, Ignore Order

Tags: arrays, set, match, octave

It seems like this should be easy, but I've been struggling with this for a couple hours now... I have a couple of arrays, of the same size, and I want to return true if both elements contain the exact same elements, ignoring order.

```octave
[1,2], [2,1] # should return true
[1,2], [2,2] # should return false
```

`intersect()` fails because `intersect([2,2], [1,2])`, `intersect([2,2], [2,2])` will both return `2`, and there is no way for me to distinguish that the first case is false for my purposes, while the second case is true.

`setdiff` fails because order matters.  `setdiff([1,2], [2,2])` returns `1`, so it shows there is a difference between the sets and gives the info I need.  However, `setdiff([2,2], [1,2])` returns emtpy, when I need something that would let me know the sets aren't the same (minus order).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `setdiff` twice:

```octave
d1 = setdiff(a,b);
d2 = setdiff(b,a);
match = (length(d1)+length(d2)==0);
```

`a` and `b` are equal if and only if both set differences are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I finally just worked out.

```
match = Sort(x) == Sort(y)
match = union(1, match)
```

then if match == 1, its true, otherwise, false.  seems like there should be something better, based on sets and not sorting